# create user with xmppframework

Tags: ios, swift, ejabberd, xmppframework

I'm currently trying to setup a chat functionality by using `ejabberd`

I'm using the `xmppframework` to communicate with my `ejabberd` server.

What I'm trying to do is the following.

```
@IBAction func registerUser(_ sender: Any) {
        var username: String = ""
        var password: String = ""

        let elements: NSMutableArray = []



        if let user = tf_user.text {
            username = "\(user)@192.168.1.19"
            elements.add(XMLElement(name: "username", stringValue: username))
        }

        if let pass = tf_password.text {
            password = pass
            elements.add(XMLElement(name: "password", stringValue: password))
        }

        if username != "" && password != "" {
            if stream.supportsInBandRegistration() {
                do {
                    try stream.register(withElements: elements as! [Any])
                } catch let error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However when I make the register call I get the following error

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="192.168.1.19" type="error">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:register">
<username>user1@192.168.1.19</username>
<password>pass</password>
</query><error code="400" type="modify">
<bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
<text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Malformed username</text></error></iq>
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? I feel like it has something to do with adding my element.

Comment: As per your error, Username that you are trying to send is wrong. It should be string. Try removing @ from the username. I guess it should work.

Comment: it is a string?